# PRISM module with DI unable to navigate view

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Quite new to Prism's module and I am using prism 7, I have a module that registers its View/ViewModel and other services:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) 
{
      containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();
      containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ILoginManager, LoginManager>();
      containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ILoginAPIService, LoginAPIService>();
}
```

The other services that are included inside the manager/apiservice are registered in my `App.xaml.cs`

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
      containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IServiceEntityMapper, ServiceEntityMapper>();
}
```

Who has a ViewModel constructor

```
 ILoginManager LoginManager;
 public LoginViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService, ILoginManager loginManager) : base(navigationService, pageDialogService)
 {
       LoginManager = loginManager;
 }
```

However, whenever I inject the `ILoginManager` seems like I cannot navigate to it, it doesn't give me any exception nor crashes, is there something wrong with how I register my services? Also, removing the `ILoginManager` able me to navigate to it again

Comment: The navigation provides a result, what does it say?

Comment: @Haukinger Do you mean the NavigationServiceAsync method?

Comment: If you do: `var result = await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginView");`, result.Success should be false and result.Exception should not be null... the exception inside that result should help give you a clue as to the problem... if you're still unsure try a try/catch in your OnInitialized and try to resolve your services/viewmodel and view..one of them is your likely problem.

Comment: Hi @DanS. was able to fix my problem, the cause was because of my APIService was trying to convert an empty string of type URI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem, it was my APIServiceBase that was causing the error as my empty string base address cannot be converted into Uri.